# Font awesome icon placed top right corner of input within table

Tags: css, input, font-awesome

I'd like an icon placed on top right hand corner of my input.  The input is inside a table column (https://jsfiddle.net/3zLzfz04/)
What's the best way of doing this?

Sample code with input styled:
HTML:

```css
.inpHours{
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    height: 47px;
    width: 47px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="sample-table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="hours_entered">
       <input class="inpHours" type="number"/>
       <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o status-icon"></i>
    </td>    
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
tr td.hours_entered{
  position: relative;
}

.inpHours{
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    height: 47px;
    width: 47px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

tr td.hours_entered .status-icon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="sample-table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="hours_entered">
       <input class="inpHours" type="number"/>
       <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o status-icon"></i>
    </td>    
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the rest of the layout of your table, but how about putting a position:relative on the td and absolute on the font awesome icon?

https://jsfiddle.net/3zLzfz04/1/

```
.hours_entered {
  position: relative;
}

.within {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

And:

```
<table id="sample-table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="hours_entered">
       <input class="inpHours" type="number"/>
       <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o status-icon within"></i>
    </td>    
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS code:

```
.hours_entered > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 44px;
}
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zLzfz04/2/).